# Formatting a csv file I'm sorting

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting, format

I'm currently sorting a csv file. As far as my output, its correct but it isn't properly formatted. The following is the file I'm sorting
[image]

And here is the output after I sort (I'll include the code after the image)
[image]

Obviously I'm having a delimiter issue, but here is my code:

```
with open(out_file, 'r') as unsort:##Opens OMI Data
    with open(Pandora_Sorted,'w') as sort:##Opens file to write to
        for line in unsort:
            if "Datetime" in line:##Searches lines
                writer=csv.writer(sort, delimiter = ',')
                writer.writerow(headers)##Writes header
            elif "T13" in line:
                writer=csv.writer(sort)
                writer.writerow(line)##Writes to output file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easier to read the csv file into a pandas data frame and sort, please check below sample code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
df.sort_values(by = ['Datetime'], inplace = True)
df.to_csv(output_file)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that out!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to be explicit about your separator for the writer?

Here in the second line of your `elif`:

```
elif "T13" in line:
    writer=csv.writer(sort, delimiter = ',')
    writer.writerow(line)  # Writes to output file
```

Answer (score 0):

For provided code, the header also would also have formatting similar to other rows due to following line:

```
writer=csv.writer(sort, delimiter = ',')
```

Using `pandas` following can be used for sorting in ascending order by list of columns, `list_of_columns`

```
import csv
import pandas as pd 

input_csv = pd.read_csv(out_file, sep=',')
input_csv.sort_values(by=list_of_columns, ascending=True)
input_csv.to_csv(Pandora_Sorted, sep=',')
```

for e.g. `list_of_columns` could be

```
list_of_columns = ['Datetime', 'JulianDate', 'repetition']
```